# ASP.NET bootstrap toggleable tabs with parameterised hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, querystringparameter

I have an ASP.NET web forms (not MVC) I have the following bootstrap nav...

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li><asp:HyperLink ID="en" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" data-toggle="tab" /></li>
<li><asp:HyperLink ID="fr" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx?lang=fr" data-toggle="tab" /></li>
</ul>
```

Clicking the 'English' link works fine.  Clicking the 'Francais' link fails.  It appears jquery does not like the querystring parameter in the NavigateUrl.

Any workarounds?

Comment: **how** does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Use `anchors` instead:

```
<a id="us" href='<%: ResolveUrl("~/About.aspx") %>' data-toggle="tab">USA</a>
<a id="fr" href='<%: ResolveUrl("~/About.aspx?lang=fr") %>' data-toggle="tab">France</a>
```